# how to make custom key in soft keyboard in android

Tags: android, xml, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to develope custome soft keyboard in android, I am want change color of outptut text of key when I press on th key, my idea is by make class extends key by this code:

```
public class k extends Key{
    private Paint mTextPaint;

    public k(Resources arg0, Row arg1, int arg2, int arg3,XmlResourceParser arg4) {
        super(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
        initLabelView();
        AttributeSet attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(arg4);
        TypedArray a =arg0.obtainAttributes(attributes, R.styleable.LabelView);
        setTextColor(a.getColor(R.styleable.LabelView_textColor, 0xFF000000));
         a.recycle();
         initLabelView();
    }


private final void initLabelView() {
        mTextPaint = new Paint();
        mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(16);
        mTextPaint.setColor(0xFF000000);

      }
public void setTextColor(int color) {
    mTextPaint.setColor(color);

}

    }
```

and set the attrs xml file in the value folder (like custom view)

and in xml folder I I made xml file for keyboard to consist the row and keys by this code:

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:keyWidth="14.28%p"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.szlosek.keying"
    android:horizontalGap="0px" android:verticalGap="0px" android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height">

    <Row>


        <Key android:codes="121"
            android:textColor="#26E80C"
             android:keyLabel="d"/>

        <com.szlosek.keying.k 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:codes="117" 
            app:textColor="#26E80C"
            android:keyLabel="u"  />


-->
    </Row>


</Keyboard>
```

my problem is the key that I customed it (that has lable u) not appear in keyboard and and the other appear( like has labled)
please any one help me and edit on my code
thanks

Comment: have you resolved this problem.